# The EXCEPTION clause is not working properly in Postgresql 12

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I wrote a function to test TRY...EXCEPT in PLPGSQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dotest(wid INTEGER, wname VARCHAR, wcost REAL) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
    DECLARE
        wdivide REAL;
    BEGIN
        wdivide := wcost / wid;
        RETURN 10;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN sqlstate '22012' THEN
            RETURN 1;
        WHEN sqlstate '22P02' THEN
            RETURN 2;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

If I input `wcost = 0`, the EXCEPTION clause will work and SELECT will return 1.

```sql
SELECT dotest(0, 'AAAAA', 12.2);
```

But if I input `wcost = 'something'`, the EXCEPTION clause doesn't work.

The EXCEPTION '22P02' is not read. The return should be 2.

```sql
SELECT dotest('a', 'AAAAA', 12.2);
```

```sql
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "a"
LINE 1: SELECT dotest('a', 'AAAAA', 12.2);
                      ^
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 15
```

Would someone help me understand what's going on?

ps. I'm running Postgresql 12.

Comment: The function is not even called, because the function you declared takes only integers. `22P02` is a compile-time exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered by user Bergi. Actually, the error is occurring before entering the function. Thanks.